# Processing help need to know where is every vertex or quad is

Tags: processing

i need to know where every vertex, quad is of an OBJ made of quads 
for example, this, but with my own OBJ

```java
PShape ps;
int lastv;

void setup(){
  ps = createShape();
  ps.beginShape();
  //// add two "starter" vertices
  ps.vertex(width/2,height/2);
  ps.vertex(10+width/2,height/2);
  ps.vertex(5+width/2,-10+height/2);
  ps.endShape(CLOSE);
}
void draw(){
  // background(0);
  shape(ps,0,0);
}


void mousePressed(){
  ps.beginShape();
  ps.vertex(mouseX,mouseY);
  ps.endShape(CLOSE);
  lastv = ps.getVertexCount()-1;
  println("Adding vertex: ", lastv , ps.getVertex(lastv));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question. You're the one adding the vertexes, so you already know where the points are.

You could add instances of `PVector` to an `ArrayList` as you add them to the shape. But your `ps` variable already contains all of them. You can loop through the points using the `getVertex()` function.

If that doesn't help, then please try to be more specific about exactly what you're trying to do. What's your end goal here?

Comment: PShape ps;

void setup(){

ps = loadShape("perfectobj,obj");
}
void draw(){

  shape(ps,0,0);
  println("where is located every vertex of the shape");
}

Comment: @vNeanderthalCruz Loading a shape and calling the `vertex()` function are two very different things. Either way, please see my answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937648/processing-obj-extract-vertex).

Comment: ty i did with blender :D

Answer (score 0):

```
PShape ps;

void setup(){

ps = loadShape("perfectobj,obj");
}
void draw(){

  shape(ps,0,0);
  println("where is located every vertex of the shape");
}
```